# how can I cat two files with a matching string in the filename?

Tags: python, python-2.7, filenames, cat

So I have a directory with ~162K files. Half of these files have the file name "`uniquenumber.fasta`" and the other half of the files have the file name "`uniquenumber.fasta letters`". For example:

```
12345.fasta
12345.fasta Somebacterialtaxaname
67890.fasta
67890.fasta Someotherbacterialtaxaname
...for another many thousand "pairs"
```

I would like to cat together the two files that share the unique fasta number. It does not matter the order of the concatenation (i.e. which contents comes first in the newly created combined file). I have tried some renditions of grep in the command line and a few lousy python scripts but I feel like this is more of a trivial problem than I am making it. Suggestions?

Comment: so the filenames are actually `12345.fasta"\t"Escherichiacoli` with the two double-quote `"` characters and the `\t` tab character embedded in them?

Comment: no, sorry, the actual file name looks like `12345.fasta Escherichiacoli`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution in Python (it will work unchanged with both Python 2 and 3). This assumes that each file `XXXXX.fasta` has one and only one matching `XXXXX.fasta stringofstuff` file.

```
import glob

fastafiles = sorted(glob.glob("*.fasta"))

for fastafile in fastafiles:
    number = fastafile.split(".")[0]
    space_file = glob.glob(number + ".fasta *")
    with open(fastafile, "a+") as fasta:
        with open(space_file[0], "r") as fasta_space:
            fasta.write("\n")
            fasta.writelines(fasta_space.readlines())
```

Here's how it works: first, the names of all `*.fasta` files are put into a list (I sort the list, but it's not strictly necessary). Next, the filename is split on `.` and the first part (the number in the filename) is stored. Then, we search for the matching `XXXXX.fasta something` file and, assuming there's only one of them, we open the `.fasta` file in append mode and the `.fasta something` file in read mode. We write a newline to the end of the `.fasta` file, then read in the contents of the "space file" and write them to the end of the `.fasta` file. Since we use the `with` context manager, we don't need to specifically close the files when we're done.

Comment: Very nice. I actually ended up figuring out how to do it and used a similar philosophy, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

There's probably many ways to achieve this, but the first that came to my head would be to use the unix command `find`.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find#Execute_an_action

The `find` command will print the filename that follows the pattern you specify. Using the `-name` and `-exec` flags, you can specify what characters should be in the file name, or run an additional command to filter the output.

If I was solving this problem, I would probably cycle over all files in the directory, and run either a `-name` pattern or `-exec` pattern that would "find" the matching file. Then `|` the two file names to a `cat` and redirect that output to a new file, hopefully concatenating the two. Hope that helps!

Comment: Please give a working example of what you would do, otherwise this answer is not very helpful.

Comment: Where did he say that this is homework? Generally the way this site works is someone asks a question, and others give useful answers. There are exceptions, of course - obvious homework dumps, questions only consisting of a list of requirements with no discernable effort expended, etc., but this is not one of those cases. Just waving your hands in the air and mentioning `find` along with a few options, and not giving any clear explanation of how exactly to use those options in a working example, is the definition of "not useful" (see the hover text over the downvote button).

Comment: So I was able to use  code `find . -name 'string' -exec cat {} \; > newfile` to cat together the contents of files whose names contain the matching string 'string'. However, I need to iterate this process through thousands of lines with a unique 'string' each time. I have a separate file where these unique strings are arranged one per line. Can I give the above code this file as input?

Comment: Surely. Similar to how you can redirect your output to the newfile, you should be able to redirect input by using `< inputfile`